# Laravel y MySQL error SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Estoy teniendo un inconveniente con una consulta, se trata de una consulta usando foreing key, las tablas tienen la siguiente estructura:

```
-productos:
---id
---titulo
---cod_articulo
---categoria_id
---marca_id

-farmacias:
---id
---titulo
---logo

-farmacia_producto:
---id
---farmacia_id
---producto_id
---web
```

La migración quedó de esta forma:

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('farmacia_id');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('producto_id');
$table->foreign('farmacia_id')->references('id')->on('farmacias')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->foreign('producto_id')->references('id')->on('productos')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->unique(['farmacia_id', 'producto_id']);
```

El modelo FarmaciaProducto quedó de la siguiente forma:

```
class FarmaciaProducto extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'farmacia_producto';

    protected $fillable = [
        'farmacia_id', 'producto_id', 'web',
    ];

    public function producto() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Producto::class);
    }
}
```

Farmacia.php

```
class Farmacia extends Model {
    protected $table = 'farmacias';

    protected $fillable = [
        'titulo', 'logo', 'web',
    ];

    public function productos() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Producto::class);
    }
}
```

Producto.php

```
protected $table = 'productos';

protected $fillable = [
    'titulo','cod_articulo', 'categoria_id', 'marca_id'
];

public function farmaciasProductos() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(FarmaciaProducto::class, 'farmacias', 'farmacia_id', 'producto_id');
}
```

El error que estoy teniendo es el siguiente:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'farmacias.farmacia_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `farmacia_producto`.*, `farmacias`.`farmacia_id` as `pivot_farmacia_id`, `farmacias`.`id` as `pivot_id` from `farmacia_producto` inner join `farmacias` on `farmacia_producto`.`id` = `farmacias`.`id` where `farmacias`.`farmacia_id` = 1)

La situación es la siguiente:

- un producto existe en muchas farmacias
- una farmacia tiene muchos productos

Mi intención es que al agregar un producto, se pueda seleccionar en que farmacia puede conseguirse y se indica la url de la pagina web de la farmacia, referenciando al producto. Entonces un mismo producto se puede conseguir en varias farmacias, es esa mi intención.
¿En que me estoy equivocando?

Comment: ahmmm,,,,  te entiendo, no lo habia visto de esa forma,,, gracias por tu ayuda amigo, te comento, lo que quiero hacer es crear una tabla que me guarde el id de farmacia, del producto y una direccion web, esta direccion web  es para ubicar el producto en la web de la farmacia

Comment: otra cosita, la tabla farmacia existe, alli estan todas las farmacias existente, y en la tabla producto estan todos los productos, lo que quisiera es crear la relacion de esas tablas, tomando en cuenta que un producto puede estar en varias farmacias, entonces para un producto pueden existir en varias farmacias

Comment: perfect! te entiendo,  agregue el campo web mediante otra migracion, de agregar columna a la tabla farmacia_producto, aplique php artisan migrate y corrio perfect.  en esta condicion $table->unique(['farmacia_id', 'producto_id']); quiero es indicarle que es unico, esta bien

Comment: entiendo, reviso el link, mil gracias amigo

Comment: estoy teniendo inconvenientes, voy a modificar la pregunta,

Comment: entendido, mil gracias bro,... tengo una duda, a la hora de agregar la web a la tabla  farmacia_producto, como se hace?, ya que no existe el modelo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El modelo `FarmaciaProducto` no va, puedes eliminarlo. Ten en cuenta que es una tabla intermedia (o pivot), y normalmente no tienen un modelo correspondiente, sólo muy raras excepciones se justificaría.

Si lo que quieres hacer es una relación Muchos a Muchos entre `Producto` y `Farmacia`, en el modelo `Producto` debes definir la relación con el modelo `Farmacia`, y no con `FarmaciaProducto`.

Sería algo así:

```php
public function farmacias() { 
    return $this->belongsToMany(Farmacia::class, 'farmacia_producto', 'producto_id', 'farmacia_id'); 
}
```

Luego para obtener las farmacias que tengan ese producto, podrás hacer, por ejemplo:

```php
$producto = Producto::find($id);
$farmacias_de_ese_producto = $producto->farmacias;
```

Para responder a *¿En que me estoy equivocando?*:

Básicamente, te estás equivocando en la definición de la relación.

```php
public function farmaciasProductos() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(FarmaciaProducto::class, 'farmacias', 'farmacia_id', 'producto_id');
}
```

Ya mencioné el problema del modelo al que quieres relacionar un Producto.

Además al personalizar el nombre de la tabla intermedia, y los nombres de las columnas de las claves de la tabla cuando le pasas argumentos adicionales.

- Va primero el nombre del modelo relacionado (pones `FarmaciaProducto::class` y debería ser `Farmacia::class`)
- Segundo el nombre de la tabla intermedia (pones `'farmacias'` y debería ser `'farmacia_producto'`)
- Tercero es el nombre de la clave foránea del modelo en el que estás definiendo la relación (pones `'farmacia_id'` y como estás definiendo la relación en el modelo `Producto`, debería ser `'producto_id'`)
- Y cuarto, es el nombre de la clave foránea del modelo al que se está uniendo (pones `'producto_id'` y como el modelo al que se está uniendo o relacionando es `Farmacia`, debería ser `'farmacia_id'`)

Referencia: Eloquent [Many To Many Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

---

Para la colomna adicional `web` en la tabla intermedia, puedes agregarle `->withPivot('web')` a la definición de la relación:

```php
public function farmacias() { 
    return $this->belongsToMany(Farmacia::class, 'farmacia_producto', 'producto_id', 'farmacia_id')->withPivot('web'); 
}
```

Y accedes, por ejemplo, así:

```php
$producto = Producto::find(1);
 
foreach ($producto->farmacias as $farmacia) {
    echo $farmacia->pivot->web;
}
```

Referencia: [Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns)

Comment: estoy aplicando dd( $producto->farmacias ), pero me muestra los datos de la tabla farmacia, no me muestra los datos de la tabla farmacia_producto, estoy tratando de acceder al campo web de la tabla farmacia_producto

Comment: algo me dice que lo que quiero hacer no se puede de la forma que hice, es asi?

Comment: @Murra Sí, disculpa, se me había pasado eso. Ahí lo agregué en la respuesta

Comment: @Murra Todo eso es para definir la relación y obtener los datos. Para insertar puedes leer https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships y en caso de encontrarte con algún problema, puedes abrir otra pregunta

Comment: mil gracias bro!